# странное поведение use в процедурном svg

Tags: javascript, svg

Вопрос про процедурный svg.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggKKvp?editors=1010
Проблема с `use`: он перестает работать хотя, если смотреть по DOM, все правильно. В HTML комментировал нормальный SVG.

Если заменить `use` на `rect` всё прекрасно работает или немного изменить DOM в браузере например `:viewBox="0 0 450 100"` на `viewBox="0 0 400 100"`. С чем такое связано не понимаю. Может как-то надо перерисовать?

```
defs.appendChild(rect.cloneNode(true))
svgg.appendChild(defs.cloneNode(true))
svgg.appendChild(use.cloneNode(true))
svgg.appendChild(use2.cloneNode(true))
svgg.appendChild(use3.cloneNode(true))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема была проста на 21 строчке было:

```
if(i === 'href')
```

А нужно было заменить на:

```
if(i === 'xlink:href')
```

Как-то так.Простите что отвлек Вас.Спасибо всем.

Comment: Хм.. А я думал, там специально namespace добавляется. Тогда лучше вообще всё проверять на наличие неймспейса и обрабатывать соответствующим образом.

Comment: @Gotha молодец! Раз сам решил, сам и отметь свой ответ как решение - галочка ниже цифры.

Comment: @Alexandr_T да только отметить смогу завтра не понимаю зачем 2 дня ждать

Comment: @Gotha Видимо таковы правила сайта. И в этом есть своя логика - дать время ответить и другим пользователям. Может их ответ будет более ценным. Ничего тут не поделаешь, подождите.

Answer (score 2):

Начните поиск ошибки в своем коде с того, что постарайтесь не использовать в именах переменных зарезервированные имена в SVG - `rect`, `defs`, тем более `use` очень специфичной команды, которая переводит создаваемый элемент в теневой ДОМ.

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 width="450" height="100" viewBox="0 0 450 100"
  style="border:1px solid rgb(150,150,150);"> 

  <defs>
  <rect id="def-rect" x="-25" y="-25" width="50" height="50" fill="#29e" /> 
  
  </defs>
   <use xlink:href="#def-rect" transform="translate(100 50)"></use>
   <use xlink:href="#def-rect" transform="translate(200 50)"></use>
   <use xlink:href="#def-rect" transform="translate(300 50)"></use>
</svg>
```

Просто сравните с файлом на codepen

Comment: Что и где зарезервировано?

Comment: Ну наверно просто не правильно,хотя вроде конфликтов с переменными нету.Код проверял,но не чего не нашел.Поэтому и обратился.

Comment: А и не увидите конфликтов. В своей практике очень часто встречаю, что парсер XML не все ошибки отлавливает вплоть до неправильного написания команд, атрибутов. Молчит, не выдает сообщений, но программа не работает. Лучше не рисковать и сузить пространство поиска ошибок.

Comment: Что-то сомнительно...

Comment: @Alexandr_T Не в переменных дело.Я проверил

Comment: @Qwertiy https://jsfiddle.net/alwas/e4tfourz/5/  смотрите - верхний круг правильный атрибут `stroke-dasharray`, нижний  с ошибкой `stroke-dsh`. Парсер XML молчит  Атрибут просто проигнорирован .

Comment: Во-первых, парсер не xml, а html, поскольку разметка страницы - это html. Во-вторых, в html лишние (=незнакомые браузеру) атрибуты ошибкой никогда не считались, поскольку их активно развешивают. И я не уверен, что бы сделал браузер при парсинге страницы как xml. На первый взгляд, синтаксических ошибок для xml я там не вижу. Будет ли вадидироваться схема я не в курсе.

Comment: Проверил для xml - атрибут не вызывает ошибку, т. е. схема не проверяется.

Comment: @Qwertiy вы мой пример смотрели? Это файл SVG где вы увидели разметку HTML?  Если интересно, могу прислать картинку сообщения парсера XML об ошибке.

Comment: Дополнительно к странной работе парсера XML Если не закрыт тег, если нет кавычки сразу будет выведено сообщение об ошибке. Согласен, парсер html такие ошибки игнорирует, а вот парсер xml нет Предлагаю согласиться на то, что мы с вами кое-что знаем и закончить спор.

Comment: @Alexandr_T, я вижу jsfiddle, в котором svg заинлайнено в html и обрабатывается, соответственно, парсером html. Попробовал его закинуть на страницу, отдаваемую как xml и получил тот же результат.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53136/discussion-between-alexandr-t-and-qwertiy).

Comment: @Alexandr_T эта инфа интересная,но она так и не решила данную проблему((

Comment: @Gotha Тот SVG файл на codepen про который вы сказали, что он нормальный.. Ошибки показать?

Comment: @Alexandr_T за этим я сюда и пришел либо их не вижу я в svg нуб )

Comment: @Gotha добавил в ответ. Просто построчно сравните файлы, что будет непонятно, пишите

Comment: @Alexandr_T ну в svg добавились ссылки и версия.Если писать именно таким методом у меня и без этого работало,а вот процедурно когда делаю не работает . Я конечно попробую сейчас это в писать но мало вероятно что заработает. Не а не чего не поменялось